# Error installing imagick: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, software-installation, dpkg

in my ubuntu machine I'm trying to install imagick from command line, like this:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick-6.q16
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
imagemagick-6.q16 is already the newest version (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.15).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up rsyslog (8.32.0-1ubuntu4.2) ...
The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/log, refusing.
Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/log/auth.log, refusing.
Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/log/kern.log, refusing.
Unsafe symlinks encountered in /var/log/syslog, refusing.
dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 installed rsyslog package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What does it mean?

EDIT1: Added output of ls -ld /var/ /var/log/ /var/log/syslog /var/log/auth.log /var/log/kern.log

https://i.imgur.com/EWL8IH4.png

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -ld /var/ /var/log/ /var/log/syslog /var/log/auth.log /var/log/kern.log`

Comment: The message means that you or a sysadmin have replaced the `/var/log/` directory with a symbolic link to somewhere else. `rsyslog` can't know if "somewhere else" will be mounted early enough in the boot process. See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go.

Comment: Added output of @Raffa command, afaik I didn't do anything fancy with this files, is this fixable?

Comment: Please copy and paste text instead of making it into a picture ... Your `/var/` directory which should be owned by `root` is instead owned by the web-server's user `www-data` which you or a script/app you ran did ... That can be very hard to fix depending on what else you did, but start with `sudo chown root:root /var/`  then try the installation again and see if you get any errors.